# What is the difference between the file-types and filetype tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags, tag-cleanup-request, retagging

What is the difference between the [file-types](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-types) and [filetype](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filetype) tags?

Is it best to leave them as two separate tags or merge them together?

Comment: As neither of them have any tag guidelines I don't know what either of them are meant to for ...

Comment: One appears to be types of files on a system, the other more likely a keyword in an app, script or similar